# Cadastrar produto para usuario logado

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

Estou conseguindo passar o objeto por `Activity's` usando `putExtra` e retornando na outra tela com o `getSerializableExtra`.

Já criei a fk `id_usuario` na tabela produtos referente ao campo `id_user` da tabela usuarios.

Minha pergunta agora é:

Como faço para inserir o meu produto na tabela produtos vinculado com o id do usuario da tabela usuarios?
Como é que eu vou inserir esse produto? Onde que passo o ID do usuário que peguei na Activity para que seja inserido nele? Uso no `contentValues`? No método do repositório inserir? Se tiverem um exemplo ajudaria muito!

```
public ContentValues contentValues(Reporte reporte) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id_user", reporte.getIdUsuario());
    values.put("tipo", reporte.getTipoReporte());
    values.put("descricao", reporte.getDescricaoReporte());
    values.put("status", reporte.getStatusReporte());
    values.put("data", reporte.getDataAbertura());
    values.put("hora", reporte.getHoraAbertura());
    values.put("latitude", reporte.getLatitude());
    values.put("longitude", reporte.getLongitude());
    values.put("endereco", reporte.getEndereco());
    return values;
}

public long insertReporte(Reporte novoReporte) {
    long id = 0;
    try {
        ContentValues values = contentValues(novoReporte);
        id = db.insert("reportes", null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Erro: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia. 
Nesse caso você informar para o objeto Produto qual o id do usuário.

Exemplo:

```
  public ContentValues contentValues(Produto produto) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id_produto", reporte.getIdProduto());
    values.put("nome", produto.getNome());
    values.put("descricao", produto.getDescricao());
    values.put("valor", produto.getValor());

    values.put("id_usuario", produto.getUsuario()); // Aki

    return values;
}
```

Seria interessante apresentar as suas Entidades, para saber como esta esse relacionamento.

Outra dica é utilizar o framework [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/), muito bacana e ajuda muito com isso.